# Collapse if nothing is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have several bootstrap 4 collapse (http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/) that are on a page.  Each of the collapse of several check boxes.  My goal is to have a button to allow the user to close all accordions that don't have any check boxes.

The piece I am having challenge with is:

```
//Collapse accordions that have check boxes
$('.collapse-only-checked').on('click', function(){
    if ($('#accordion .collapse .item').is(':checked')) {
        $('#accordion .collapse').collapse('hide');
    event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**This function closes ALL** the accordions.  I am looking to only close the accordions that have any input(checkboxes) checked. The other accordions should stay open.

```js
//Expand & Contract Accordions Based on Button Clicks 
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Expand All
  $('.expand-all').on('click', function() {
    $('#accordion .collapse').collapse('show');
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  //Collapse All
  $('.collapse-all').on('click', function() {
    $('#accordion .collapse').collapse('hide');
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  //Collapse accordions that have check boxes
  $('.collapse-only-checked').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#accordion .collapse .item').is(':checked')) {
      $('#accordion .collapse').collapse('hide');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn-primary expand-all" href="#">Expand All</a>  <a class="btn btn-primary collapse-all" href="#">Collapse All</a>  <a class="btn btn-primary collapse-only-checked" href="#">Collapse Only That have Checked Inputs</a>

<br/>
<br/>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">

    <!-- Accordion Title -->
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
   <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#announcements-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
     <i class="icofont icofont-unique-idea"></i> Announcements </a>
    </h5>
    </div>
    <!-- //Accordion Title -->

    <!-- Accordion Content -->
    <div id="announcements-1" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" aria-expanded="true" style="">
      <div class="card-block checkboxes">

        <!-- Start Form Fields -->
        <label class="control control--checkbox">Value 0
          <input type="checkbox" class="item" value="Value 0">
          <div class="control__indicator silver"></div>
        </label>
        <label class="control control--checkbox">Value 1
          <input type="checkbox" data-type="Value 1" class="item" value="Value 1">
          <div class="control__indicator public"></div>
        </label>
        <!-- End Form Fields -->

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //Accordion Content -->

  </div>

  <div class="card">

    <!-- Accordion Title -->
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
   <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#announcements-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
     <i class="icofont icofont-unique-idea"></i> Announcements 2 </a>
    </h5>
    </div>
    <!-- //Accordion Title -->

    <!-- Accordion Content -->
    <div id="announcements-2" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" aria-expanded="true" style="">
      <div class="card-block checkboxes">

        <!-- Start Form Fields -->
        <label class="control control--checkbox">Value 0
          <input type="checkbox" class="item" value="Value 0">
          <div class="control__indicator silver"></div>
        </label>
        <label class="control control--checkbox">Value 1
          <input type="checkbox" data-type="Value 1" class="item" value="Value 1">
          <div class="control__indicator public"></div>
        </label>
        <!-- End Form Fields -->

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //Accordion Content -->

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a runnable code example on jsfiddle or with the built-in tool by stackoverflow.

Comment: Look at this and update your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Well, I feel the question is clear.

Comment: OK, I fixed my code so that it's more self-explanatory.

Comment: @Claud I got the stuff... Lemme update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is:

```
//Collapse accordions that have check boxes
$('.collapse-only-checked').on('click', function() {
  $("#accordion .collapse").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('.item:checked').length > 0)
      $(this).collapse('hide');
  });
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Simple explanation is:

1. Go through each and every `.collapse`.
2. Check the count of `:checked` checkboxes.
3. If the count is greater than 0, which means, some checkbox is checked:

   - Collapse the accordion.
     Else
   - Do nothing.

See the `if` condition:

```js
//Expand & Contract Accordions Based on Button Clicks 
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Expand All
  $('.expand-all').on('click', function() {
    $('#accordion .collapse').collapse('show');
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  //Collapse All
  $('.collapse-all').on('click', function() {
    $('#accordion .collapse').collapse('hide');
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  //Collapse accordions that have check boxes
  $('.collapse-only-checked').on('click', function() {
    $("#accordion .collapse").each(function () {
      if ($(this).find('.item:checked').length > 0)
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn-primary expand-all" href="#">Expand All</a>  <a class="btn btn-primary collapse-all" href="#">Collapse All</a>  <a class="btn btn-primary collapse-only-checked" href="#">Collapse Only That have Checked Inputs</a>

<br/>
<br/>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">

    <!-- Accordion Title -->
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#announcements-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          <i class="icofont icofont-unique-idea"></i> Announcements </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <!-- //Accordion Title -->

    <!-- Accordion Content -->
    <div id="announcements-1" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" aria-expanded="true" style="">
      <div class="card-block checkboxes">

        <!-- Start Form Fields -->
        <label class="control control--checkbox">Value 0
          <input type="checkbox" class="item" value="Value 0">
          <div class="control__indicator silver"></div>
        </label>
        <label class="control control--checkbox">Value 1
          <input type="checkbox" data-type="Value 1" class="item" value="Value 1">
          <div class="control__indicator public"></div>
        </label>
        <!-- End Form Fields -->

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //Accordion Content -->

  </div>

  <div class="card">

    <!-- Accordion Title -->
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#announcements-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          <i class="icofont icofont-unique-idea"></i> Announcements 2 </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <!-- //Accordion Title -->

    <!-- Accordion Content -->
    <div id="announcements-2" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" aria-expanded="true" style="">
      <div class="card-block checkboxes">

        <!-- Start Form Fields -->
        <label class="control control--checkbox">Value 0
          <input type="checkbox" class="item" value="Value 0">
          <div class="control__indicator silver"></div>
        </label>
        <label class="control control--checkbox">Value 1
          <input type="checkbox" data-type="Value 1" class="item" value="Value 1">
          <div class="control__indicator public"></div>
        </label>
        <!-- End Form Fields -->

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //Accordion Content -->

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you just use the `.collapse('hide')` as mentioned in the documentation. for instance if you wanted to close all the accordians on a page.

```
 $.each($('.panel-collapse'), function() { 
       $(this).collapse('hide');
   });
```

if you want to further filter add it to your selector in jquery. so you could filter out the ones with checkboxes or whatever you want.  below is a runnable example where you can close all accordians with the click of a button

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#closeAll').click(function(event) {
    $.each($('.panel-collapse'), function() {
      $(this).collapse('hide');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn btn-danger" id="closeAll">
  Close All Accordions
</button>

<!--accordian one -->
<h3>
Accordion One
</h3>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- accordian 2 -->
<h3>
Accordian Two
</h3>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne2">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne2">
          Collapsible Group 2 Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne2">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo2">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo2">
          Collapsible Group 2 Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo2">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree2">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree2">
          Collapsible Group 2 Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree2">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- accordian 2 -->
<h3>
Accordian Three
</h3>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion3" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne3">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapseOne3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne3">
          Collapsible Group 3 Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne3">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo3">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo3">
          Collapsible Group 3 Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo3">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree3">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapseThree3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree3">
          Collapsible Group 3 Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree3">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```